# IBM Analytics for Apache Spark: Precipitation Analysis sample notebook - get_file_content() issue

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud

In the Precipitation Analysis sample notebook on IBM Analytics for Apache Spark, I get the following error message when I access a data file on my associated Object Storage:

`<html><h1>Not Found</h1><p>The resource could not be found.</p></html>`

The error is raised after the following code:

```
content_string = get_file_content(credentials)
precipitation_df = pd.read_csv(content_string)
precipitation_df.head()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this issue is an enhancement of Bluemix Object Storage V3.
See here for the solution and more information:

https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/2016/01/26/bluemix-object-storage-enhanced-update-precipitation-analysis-sample-notebook/